# Use of TLS v1 for ArtemisTcpTransport

Tags: ssl, kotlin, corda

we have realized our communications between nodes are using TLSv1. However checking ArtemisTcpTransport.kt class it looks like only v1.2 is supported:

```
val TLS_VERSIONS = listOf("TLSv1.2")
```

I would like to use v1.2 in our communications. Is that possible ?

Comment: What indicated to you that the node were communicating using TLS 1?

Answer (score 0):

Corda nodes do communicate using TLS 1.2. See https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html#keypair-and-certificate-formats.

Comment: Hi, thanks you are rigth but our problem is TLS v1 is enable in the system. If I run "openssl s_client -connect IP:port -tls1" I get a sucessfully respond. Is there a way to disable TLS v1 in corda? Thanks!!